# How to change profile picture?

Tags: support

This is my first question on the meta site and I have absolutely no idea if this would be acceptable to the community. But still, here goes.

To change my profile picture, I click "edit" on my profile page. Then I click "change picture". But this redirects me to [**this page**](http://en.gravatar.com/) where the I am supposed to sign up for a website (which I believe has nothing to do with El&U).

So, my question is that, am I following the right procedure? If yes, should I sign up for that website? If yes again, why should I sign up for a completely different website, when all I want to do is to upload a picture from my PC?

Comment: Yes; you need to go through Gravatar to change your picture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is the right procedure. Gravatar is used on many sites (e.g. http://github.com and http://wordpress.com) as well as the whole Stack Exchange network.

Using Gravatar is the only way to get your choice of avatar here, unless you're happy with the default.